# How to make a turtle object look at where the mouse has clicked

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to write a `turtle` program where the turtle goes to wherever you click. So far I have this:

```
from turtle import *
screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()
screen.onscreenclick(turtle.goto)
```

But the problem is the turtle object just stays facing in the same direction. I want to somehow make it look towards where it's going. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Trigonometry? Use a reference angle between the baseline of it's current position and the clicked location. Then use trigonometry to compute the angle, then rotate the turtle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do what you describe:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
turtle = turtle.Turtle()

def turtle_headto(x, y):
    turtle.left(turtle.towards(x, y) - turtle.heading())
    turtle.goto(x, y)

screen.onscreenclick(turtle_headto)

screen.mainloop()
```

But the motion of the arrow/turtle isn't always optimal, i.e. sometimes it spins the long way 'round, but that's something for you to optimize (e.g. when to call `left()` and when to call `right()`)

Comment: Ok I tested it, and it worked, then I made a few changes to get my game further. Now it isn't working properly `import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t.up()
t2.shape('turtle')
def turtle_headto(x, y):
    t.left(turtle.towards(x, y) - turtle.heading())
    t.goto(x, y)
t2.up()
t2.left(180)
t2.goto(50,50)
s.onscreenclick(turtle_headto)

s.mainloop()
`

Comment: Try changing `t.left(turtle.towards(x, y) - turtle.heading())` to instead read `t.left(t.towards(x, y) - t.heading())` and see if that helps.  Any further issues, please post a new question!